# EF Database First "CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'."

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, ef-database-first

I have 2 web projects -one is Content Management (CMS1) and the other is a website (website2).  These were both converted to MVC and EF Database First a while ago and have been working fine.  A week ago I added asp Identity to the cms1 project using Code-First - that is now running ok.  The website2, however, is now giving me the "Create Database permission denied..." error.

I am using these on a common domain: xxx.com/cms1/   and xxx.com/website2/
cms1 has the code-first model that is connected to a DB called AuthDb.
cms1 also has a database-first model connection to a DB called dbData.
All good - this works.

website2 has a database-first connection to 2 dbs - DbTracking (tracking data) and dbData (reads the content entered through cms1)

I have not done any code-first things on website2.
The connection strings both have the db-first meta strings

In the context I have this for both models.

```
        public db()
        : base("name=db")
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<db>(null);
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }
```

There is no migration folder since it has always been database first.

When I open website2 I get the error "Create Database permission denied..." but I don't know why the project is trying to create a database at this point since it has always been db-first...  plus I have added Database.SetInitializer(null) to prevent it.

Not sure what else to do...?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like when I created the website2 app I did this using individual account authentication even though I never used it. I am not sure why but after changing the cms app to use authentication the website2 app started trying to create the authentication database.  So my solution was to start over with website2 using no authentication.  Seems to be working